# Extending allocated primary partition with preceding unallocated volume

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-space

I tried to make a dual-boot system on my Razer Blade.
When I allocated a seperate partition for my Linux installation,
I suddenly got a new unallocated partition in front of my Windows partition.
Now I can't merge the C partition with the unallocated space in front of it,
nor can I extend the partition to have enough space to be usable with my desired Linux installation.
***(TLDR)* How do I make the unallocated space usable again?**

[image: Diskmanager Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unallocated space is in the wrong place. You may only extend a partition
*downwards*, so this space must *follow* the partition of C.

You need to boot a partition editor, since you cannot move C while also booting
from it. Then you will need to move C up to overwrite the unallocated space.
This will make this space *contiguous* to C.

You should then boot into Windows and resize C. It is best to resize Windows
using Windows. The bootable partition editor might possibly make a mistake
when handling sensitive Windows files.

This operation is dangerous, in the sense that a mistake can make the disk
unbootable. It is best to take a backup image of the disk and have a bootable
media of the backup program that can restore it in case of a severe problem
(and to test it before starting).